# Return destination nodes available to Node B that can't be accessed from Node A

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have relationships between Users and Repositories in my database.

They look like this:

```
(User{name:"A"})-[:HAS_ACCESS_TO]->(Repository{name:"1"})
(User{name:"A"})-[:HAS_ACCESS_TO]->(Repository{name:"2"})

(User{name:"B"})-[:HAS_ACCESS_TO]->(Repository{name:"1"})
(User{name:"B"})-[:HAS_ACCESS_TO]->(Repository{name:"3"})
(User{name:"B"})-[:HAS_ACCESS_TO]->(Repository{name:"4"})
```

I'm trying to find the Repositories that User B has access to that User A *does not* have access to.

In the example above, the answer would be Repositories 3 and 4 only.

I've tried something like this:

```
MATCH (u:User{name:"A"})-[]->(r:Repository)
WITH r.name AS userARepositories

MATCH (u:User{name:"B"})-[]->(r:Repository)
WHERE NOT r.name in userARepositories

RETURN r.name
```

The above doesn't work as I expected (and to be frank I'm not sure how to interpret the results returned by the above query to understand what it is doing instead).

**How can I find the repositories that User B has access to that User A *does not* have access to?**

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
MATCH (b:User {name:'B'})
WITH b
MATCH (a:User {name:'A'})
WITH a,b
MATCH (b)-—>(r:Repository)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((a)-->(r))
RETURN r.name
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting told the following in the UI, is this something we can do different?

_This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns.
If a part of a query contains multiple disconnected patterns, this will build a cartesian product between all those parts. This may produce a large amount of data and slow down query processing. While occasionally intended, it may often be possible to reformulate the query that avoids the use of this cross product, perhaps by adding a relationship between the different parts or by using OPTIONAL MATCH (identifier is: (a))_

Comment: @Juicy yes, that does not surprise me. I changed the query to avoid the cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need to return userA, you can write your query like this. Do a profiling and you will see that this is more efficient query.

```
MATCH (b:User {name:'B'})-—>(r:Repository)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((:User {name:'A'})-->(r))
RETURN r.name
```